# Chroma subsampling in jpeg compression

Tags: matlab, image-processing, jpeg, image-compression

Is the chroma sub-sampling the first step to compress an image file to jpeg image file? Is this the step that we implement in Color Space Conversion?

Comment: Did you do any research? http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Color space conversion takes place before sampling. Sub-sampling is the first step that compresses the image.